# array of excluded CGRects from 2 rects

Tags: ios

Does anybody know a way of getting the none intersecting rects when 2 CGRect overlap. the opposite of:

```
CGRect CGRectIntersection ( CGRect r1, CGRect r2 );
```

Thanks
Reza

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? `CGRectIntersection` will return a null rect (which you can check with `bool CGRectIsNull(CGRect rect)`) if the there is no intersection, furthermore you could use `CGRectIntersectsRect` which pretty much is the two steps in one.

Comment: It's not trivial, however there's an [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228510/400056) in Objective-C to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765283/how-to-subtract-a-rectangle-from-another).